# Sending MJPEG stream over http on linux using a simple tcp server in C

Tags: http, mjpeg

I am trying to write a simple TCP server for sending a MJPEG stream over http.
The client sending me :

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
CSeq: 1
User-Agent: LIVE555 Streaming Media v2013.02.11
x-sessioncookie: fc0538d3fd5b797ec31b54e
Accept: application/x-rtsp-tunnelled
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

or

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: CmRtspClient 1291
x-sessioncookie: 29953
Accept: application/x-rtsp-tunnelled
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

please what need be my response for sending a multiple numbers of jpegs?

Thanks
PF

Answer (score 1):

The client request ask for a "application/x-rtsp-tunnelled" answer, this is not a simple MJPEG stream over HTTP (multipart/x-mixed-replace with image/jpeg boundaries), this is an RTSP/RTP stream tunneled inside an HTTP stream.

Live555 provide an RTSP/RTP over HTTP server see [LIVE555 Media Server](http://www.live555.com/mediaServer/#downloading).

If you would like to stream video/JPEG stream, you need to extend Live555 [JPEG streaming with live555](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20584296/3102264)